# DateListPlot show point with a thin bar

Tags: plotting, date-and-time

I have a list of date points and I want to show each point with a single verticle line that connects the point with the x-axis.

I imagine that the solution should be the same as for a ListPlot.

Comment: use the option `Filling -> Axis` or `Filling -> Bottom`?

Comment: Ok, thanks! Any idea how to set the width of the line?

Comment: `FillingStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[x]` where x is the width (I think 1 is the default width).